# How to escape ```\n``` char which is not at the end of the line of the string using java?

Tags: java, csv

I have a csv string. A sample would be ->

```
String str = "Name, Age, Gender, Description\n"
           + "Test1, 12, M, Hello World\n"
           + "Test2, 21, M, Bye\nWorld";
```

When I open this in a csv viewer, `Bye\nWorld` is creating an issue. How do I escape the `\n` char in `Bye\nWorld` but not the ones that are at the end of each data using java? The logic should not detect the `\n` char at the end of each line, it should only detect the ones that are in the data. An example of the output I want is

```
Name, Age, Gender, Description
Test1, 12, M, Hello World
Test2, 21, M, Bye\\nWorld
```

This output will create a correct csv for this data.

Comment: Hint for you: Regex.

Comment: @Pshemo this is the string ```String test = "Name,Age,Gender,Description\nTest1,12,M,Hello World\nTest2,21,M,Bye\nWorld";```

Comment: How do you create this CSV? Usually CSV parsers would generate strings surrounded by `"` which would allow them later to determine what is part of data (like commas inside strings) and what is part of CSV metadata (like commas which are separators of different tokens).

Comment: In other words my first approach would not be solving the problem, but preventing it.

Comment: Basically I have a JSONArray like so -> 
```
{
  "Name" : "Test1",
"Age" : 10,
"Gender" : "M",
"Description" : "Hello World"

},
{
 "Name" : "Test2",
"Age" : 21,
"Gender" : "M",
"Description" : "Bye\nWorld"
}
```
Then I am doing ```String csv = CDL.toString(arr);```
This generates the above string given in the ques

Comment: Also imagine that there is `\n` at `Hello\nWorld` which would make your string something like `... ,Hello\nWorld\nTest2, ...`. How should we know which `\n` is part of string data and which one is CSV line separator? It could represent strings `,Hello` and `World\nTest2` but also `Hello\nWorld` and `Test2`. To prevent this kind of problem build CSV using proper CSV parsers which are designed for that job.

Comment: @Pshemo I have added the correct ques in this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63062478/converting-a-jsonarray-to-csv-using-java
Can you pls check?