# Converting a JSONArray to csv using java

Tags: java, csv, org.json

I have a JSONArray like this ->

```
[ 
{ "Name" : "Test1", "Age" : 10, "Gender" : "M", "Description" : "Hello World" }, 
{ "Name" : "Test2", "Age" : 21, "Gender" : "M", "Description" : "Bye\nWorld" }
]
```

I need to convert this into a csv format. I was using  `org.json.CD` to achieve this like so
`String csv = CDL.toString(arr);` where `arr` is the JSONArray as given above. The generated csv string is `Name,Age,Gender,Description\nTest1,12,M,Hello World\nTest2,21,M,Bye\nWorld`. The csv output of this would be something like this

```
Name,Age,Gender,Description
Test1,12,M,Hello World
Test2,21,M,Bye
World
```

But that is not the correct conversion. The correct conversion would have been

```
Name,Age,Gender,Description
Test1,12,M,Hello World
Test2,21,M,Bye\nWorld
```

There is no way to manually change this string `Name,Age,Gender,Description\nTest1,12,M,Hello World\nTest2,21,M,Bye\nWorld` to something like `Name,Age,Gender,Description\nTest1,12,M,Hello World\nTest2,21,M,Bye\\nWorld`How do I solve this problem?

PS The values in the JSONArray(name, age, gender, description) are not fixed. I am looking for a way to solve a problem like so in a generic fashion

Comment: you said you cant manually change the json manually. does that mean that you cant run a functhion prior to it? why? whats stopping you from scanning the json string prior to the conversion and change things- from \n to \\n and then run the conversion?

Comment: Try  https://jtablesaw.github.io/tablesaw/userguide/importing_data.html Importing & exporting data. https://github.com/jtablesaw/tablesaw

Answer (score 0):

Instead of generating CSV data "manually" use CSV parser (like OpenCSV) to generate it for you. This way instead of

```
Test2,21,M,Bye
World
```

you will get format like

```
Test2,21,M,"Bye
World"
```

or

```
"Test2","21","M","Bye
World"
```

which same parser will be able to properly read back to original data.

DEMO:

```
//writing CSV
StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();//to create String for demonstration purpose
CSVWriter csvWriter = new CSVWriter(sw);

String[] array = {"Test2","21","M","Bye\nWorld"};
csvWriter.writeNext(array,false);

String csvString = sw.toString();
System.out.println(csvString);

//reading CSV
CSVReader csvReader = new CSVReader(new StringReader(csvString));
//in case of many lines
for (String[] line : csvReader){//in case of many lines

    for (String cell : line){//handle each line
        System.out.print("<"+cell + ">");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Output:

```
Test2,21,M,"Bye
World"

<Test2><21><M><Bye
World>
```

As you see

```
"Bye
World"
```

is properly interpreted as single `cell` with line separator character (`\n`) and was able to be print as

```
<Bye
World>
```